# Install4j run the command: apt-get -y install npm

Tags: install4j

I am trying to run the commands:
apt-get -y install npm
apt-get -y install nodejs
using install4j.
OS: Ubunto.

I tried to add sh file with those commands (but it not run).
Tried to run:

## !/bin/bash

apt-get -y install npm
apt-get -y install nodejs
exit 0

But with Install4j it now run.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to make the shell script file executable in the installer before trying to run it.

Comment: How do i run chmod +x in install4j ?

Comment: You need to use the "Set the UNIX access mode of files and directories" action for that particular script before running it.